# how to return a word from a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, return-type

I apologize for the messy code, but these are two methods are ones we are supposed to use. I have to find the word `end` in a given string, if there is no end in the string return an empty string. ex (the, end said the author) output= the end

```
public class end {

    /**
    * find first apperance of the word end.
     * return the string up to word end
     * return empty string if the word end isn't there 
     */

    public static int endArray(String[] words) {
        int end = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i ++) {
            end ++;
            if (words[i] == "end") {
                end++;
            } else {
                end = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String end(String[] words) {
        String end = "-1";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i ++) {
            end+= words[i];
            if (words[i] == "end") {
                System.out.println(words[i-1]);
                end++;
            }

        }    
        return end;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out why the output of given string `(the, end said the author)` is `the end`. How did you split the string into a string array?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know, that it's incorrect to compare strings with `==` use the `equals` method instead:
`if ("end".equals(words[1])) { ...`

I'd implement it like that:

```
public static String end(String[] words) {
    String allStrings = ""; // actually, it'd be better to use StringBuilder, but for your goal string concatination is enough
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if ("end".equals(words[i])) {
            return allStrings;
        }
        allStrings += words[i]; // maybe here we should add spaces ?
    }
    // the word 'end' hasn't been found, so return an empty string
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, would the following code you provided match my output? for instance a string like (The, end said the author) ouput = ("The End")

Comment: the method returns everything _before_ end, so if you need to include the word `end` to the returned string, it should look like `return allStrings + "end"`. Second thing here is how you get an array from the string. So if you do something like that: `"The, end said the author".split(" ")`, then out string (with my previous changes) will be `The,end` (note there's no space and there's a comma, because it was in your string). Third, in the input string "The, end said the author" contains `end` with the letter 'e' in lower case, but you expect "End", with upper case. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public  String getSortedGrades(String[] arg){
    String newStr = "";
    for(int i=0; i<arg.length; i++){
        if(arg[i]=="end"){
            newStr+=arg[i];
            return newStr;
        }else{
            newStr+=arg[i]+" ";
        }
    }
    return newStr.contains("end")?newStr: " " ;
}
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Main m =new Main();
        String[] input ={"the", "end", "said", "the", "author"}; 
       String s =  m.getSortedGrades(input);
       System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```